# CQ5 Querydebugger returning the results excluding the path given

Tags: aem

I am trying to get the values from mysite using querydebugger tool, my home page has a value Inicio in pageTitle field. my query is very simple, i.e search pageTitle with value Inicio anywhere in the path  /content/mysite/es and beneath

```
path=/content/mysite/es
type=cq:Page
fulltext=Inicio
fulltext.relPath=jcr:content/@pageTitle
```

which gives me the following xpath query

```
/jcr:root/content/mysite/es//element(*, cq:Page)
[
jcr:contains(jcr:content/@pageTitle, 'Inicio') 
]
```

When I run I don't get the results from home page /content/mysite/es, but it gives results below this node

I tried different option to get the results including the path given and its child pages but didn't work for me.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `path.self=true` in order to include the given path along with its subtree in the search. Else it searches only subtree.

```
path=/content/mysite/es
path.self=true
type=cq:Page
fulltext=Inicio
fulltext.relPath=jcr:content/@pageTitle
```

Further properties supported can be found [here](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/PathPredicateEvaluator.html)